# Uniswap Pairs Added Script

Tags: node.js, solidity

I am not sure if my script is working 100% as I do get logging inside the 'factory.on(' function however they are very sparse.

I get around 3 to 5 Pairs added a day running the script all day. Does this sound correct? And if it isn't then what could possibly be the issue?

I am running on mainnet and testnet using Infura.

```
const factory = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.factory,
  ['event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)'],
  account
);

const router = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.router,
  [
    'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
  ],
  account
);

factory.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pairAddress) => {......
```

Comment: The `PairCreated` event on the Uniswap V2 Factory Contract was emitted at least 30 times during the past 24 hours ([etherscan link](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5c69bee701ef814a2b6a3edd4b1652cb9cc5aa6f#events)).